# rails 4 strong parameters still unpermitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i have an issue with strong parameters in Rails 4, basically I have this params coming

```
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1", "attends"=>[{"survey_id"=>15, "question_id"=>67, "anwser_id"=>196}, {"survey_id"=>15, "question_id"=>68, "anwser_id"=>200}, {"survey_id"=>15, "question_id"=>69, "anwser_id"=>202}, {"survey_id"=>15, "question_id"=>70, "anwser_id"=>205}, {"survey_id"=>15, "question_id"=>71, "anwser_id"=>208}], "attend"=>{}}
```

and in my controller i have

```
private
def attend_params
    params.permit(:user_id, :format, :attend, :attends, {:attends => []})
end
```

but i still get this error

```
Unpermitted parameters: attends, attend
```

attend_params is called in my controller by this way, no much more, the data passed at th method create via POST are submitted by an external app. there is no view for it.

```
def create
    logger.info "\n attend_params #{attend_params}\n"
end
```

any hint?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
params.permit(:user_id, :format,
  attend: {} ,
  attends: [ :survey_id, :question_id, :anwser_id ])
```

**UPDATE**
As you can see in the screenshot attached, I create a request which results in the same set of parameters. I intentionally add a `user` param which is not permitted and you can see that `user` parameter is rejected, other parameters go through. Are you sure you have provided the correct parameters?

[image]

Comment: nothing change, always the same Unpermitted parameters: attends, attend

Comment: @MattiaLipreri Please provide the code which calls attend_params and the view code which builds the parameters that you mention in your question.